# Can I change confirm box in Form Observer plugin in Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-dialog

Form Observer plugin  gives the confirm box with our custom message. I haven't understood where they kept the code to show it up.

Because I want to change this confirm box to jQuery dialogue. Can I do that. it would be great some can throw some light on this.

Comment: Thank you clairesuzy for editing the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to replace the standard `window.confirm` with jquery dialog box?

If so, you could do something like this:

```
window.confirm = function(a){
    $('<div />').appendTo('body').text(a).dialog({close:function(){$(this).remove();}})
}
```

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/SDPYb/

Comment: Thank u for answering me. Yes. How can i put this code to form observer plugin as it is giving javascript error for mentioning window.confirm. ( its not accpting . in the function name.) I want to keep OK and cancel functionalities as for confirm box. Mainly need to change look and feel similar to jquery dialog. Thank you for the effort to answer my query

Comment: You can't. The default confirm() box waits for user input before it continues with the javascript execution. jQuery dialog (and everything similar to it), work in a way where when they are initialized, the javascript keeps on running in the background.

Comment: Sorry i didn't get you. You are saying that i can't keep your propsed code in Jquery form observer plug in. Correct?

Comment: Correct. You won't be able to replace the default `confirm` box with jquery dialog, while still keeping its functionality the same.

Comment: It replaces the default `confirm()` box as described in your question, you will however have to handle the resulting action from the dialog manually, as it can't be made to work the same way the default `confirm` dialog functions.